# Java regex pattern to match word or phrase

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regular expression, that I am compiling with Pattern class.

```
\bIntegrated\s+Health\s+System\s+\(IHS\)\b
```

Why is this not matching this string?

"test pattern  case Integrated Health System (IHS)."

If I try \bpattern\b, it seems to work, but for the above phrase it does not. I have the parenthesis in the pattern escaped, so not sure why it doesn't work. It does match if I remove the parenthesis portion of the pattern, but I want to match the whole thing.

Comment: I did escape it, stackoverflow un-escaped :). My expression reads like this:
<code>\bIntegrated\s+Health\s+System\s+\\(IHS\\)\b</code>

Comment: You should edit your question rather than adding a comment.

Comment: SO doesn't know <code> tags. Just indent with 4 spaces or select it and press `010101` button or `Ctrl+K`. Also see the Markdown FAQ on the right hand of the message editor.

Comment: Got it (indenting 4 spaces for code)! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) escape the parens, otherwise they are capturing and group metacharacters, not literal parenthesis `\( \)`

2) remove the final \b you can't use a word boundary after a literal ), since ) is not considered part of a word.

```
\bIntegrated\s+Health\s+System\s+\(IHS\)\W
```

Comment: Okay, how do I indicate the trailing boundary then, so it does not match something like 
   \bIntegrated\s+Health\s+System\s+\\(IHS\\)testing
I need to make sure it only matches the whole phrase and not some string that starts with this phrase.

Comment: you could use \W which is the same as [^\w] or [^a-bA-B0-9_] (not sure exactly what it includes in java), or you could create you own character class (or negated class) to specify what does or does not indicate a match. I've updated the example with \W which will likely work pretty well.

Comment: Thanks, \W seems to work pretty well so far combined with grouping to extract the matched phrase minus the non-word character that follows.

Comment: If you want to allow the match at the end of the string you would have to say `($|\W)`. I'm not sure it's so important though, are you likely to have strings like `Integrated Health Systems (IHS)foo`? The close bracket is almost invariably followed by space or punctuation.

Comment: Okay, here is my final regex pattern:
`"(\\b|\\W)(" + phrase + ")($|\\W)"`
Using the group 2 to get the matched phrase.

Comment: Hmm. That causes problem if the phrase begins with a "(". So modified it to `"(^|\\W)(" + phrase + ")($|\\W)"`

Answer (score 0):

You've got (IHS) - a group - where you want \(IHS\) as the literal brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parentheses

```
\bIntegrated\s+Health\s+System\s+\(IHS\)\b
```

Parentheses delimit a capture group. To match a literal set of parentheses, you can escape them like this `\( \)`

Comment: It isn’t safe to use `\b` in Java. It doesn’t mean what you think it does.  [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304928/unicode-equivalents-for-w-and-b-in-java-regular-expressions/4307261#4307261) for why.